# How to remove scroll bar using overflow CSS HTML (Possible Positioning Conflict)

Tags: jquery, html, css, conflict

I have tried everything to try and remove this bottom scroll bar but cant seem to figure it out. I'm not sure if it is something to do with the positioning.

The image (banner) is supposed to be 2000px(width) by 400px(height) but I would like it to not effect the page size by adding the scroll bar.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://goo.gl/SsxDy)**

**CSS**

```
#banner {
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #EAEAEA;
    position: relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;
    display:block;
    float:none;
    top:160px;
}
#slideshow { 
    width: 1000px; 
    display:block;
    text-align:center; 
    position:absolute;
    left:-50%;
}
#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 

}
.images {
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="banner">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div><a class="images" href="#"><img src="AG/images/bulbs.png"></a></div>
        <div><a class="images" href="#"><img src="AG/images/cables.png"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>  <!--END banner -->
```

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE**

Is there a way to only add overflow to the banner rather than the whole page? For example the same as [**EXAMPLE**](http://www.johnlewis.com/)

Comment: You should use a class for "images", not an id, since more than one element has the same id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but isn't there a way to only add overflow to the banner rather than the whole page? for example the same way this [site works](http://www.johnlewis.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap another div around the banner.

```
<div id="bannerWrapper">
    <div id="banner">
         <!--the rest of your code-->
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the CSS:

```
#bannerWrapper{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

The banner will show less on a smaller screen, and up to full width on a larger one.
Hope it helped